# Erro ao deletar um elemento do BD a partir de uma coluna

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, json, node.js, knex.js

Estou tentando criar uma funcionalidade de **Postagens** em Node. Uma postagem pode ser criada, mostrada ou excluída. Para isto criei uma tabela chamda **posts** com os seguintes campos :

```
table.string('category').notNullable()
table.string('title').notNullable()
table.string('description').notNullable()
```

Isto posto o meu sistema terá 3 operações possíveis para esta entidade de Postagem : **Create, Index (show) e Delete**. Para realizar a exclusão de uma postagem eu desejo informar o **title** de uma já presente no BD e então esta ser excluída. Eis a implementação da operação de **Destroy** no meu Controller :

```
async delete (request, response){

        const{title} = request.params

        const postagem = await connection('posts')
            .where('title', title)//significa procurar um título que seja igual ao const{title} = request.params definido acima
            .select('title')//selecionando apenas a coluna title da tabela
            .first()//como terá apenas um resultado, o first deletará o primeiro resultado do título que vier

            if(postagem.title != title){//se o título da postagem que colocamos for diferente da do título dentro do bd ...
                return response.status(401).json({error : 'Operation not permitted'})//não autorizado, ou seja, erro
            }

            await connection('posts').where('title', tile).delete()
    }
```

Feito isto, faço uma requisição do tipo **DELETE** em formato JSON da seguinte maneira :

```
{
    "title": "<titulo da Postagem a ser excluida>"
}
```

E recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro :

**(node:7699) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling FIRST. Undefined column(s): [title] query: select `title_id` from `posts` where `title` = ? limit ?**

Como posso fazer para que possa excluir uma Postagem enviando o campo title em formato JSON como demonstrado?

Comment: **Undefined column(s): [title]**

Answer (score 1):

Para qualquer alteração e/ou remoção de dados em um banco, é necessário ter o ID da linha a qual se refere.
Apenas o título não é aceito porque teoricamente podem haver outros títulos (leia-se strings) iguais, já com um ID isso não pode e nem deve ocorrer.
O objeto JSON precisa se parecer com isso:

```
{
   "title_id": 1,
   "title": "texto"
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Com base nela refatorei um pouco o meu código, e acrescentei um novo campo à minha tabela. Ela agora está da seguinte maneira :

Comment: //chave primária que se auto incrementa a cada post
        table.increments('post_id').primary

        table.string('category').notNullable()
        table.string('title').notNullable()
        table.string('description').notNullable()

Comment: Ao invés de querer excluir por 'title' agora estou passando o 'post_id'. A lógica no controller segue a mesma com a diferença de agora estar post_id (ou seja, tudo o que estiver acima como title agr está post_id). Passando o post_id em formato JSON ele não retorna nenhum erro, apenas informa a seguinte mensagem : Cannot DELETE /postagens . Você imagina o que pode ter originado isto?

Comment: Normalmente essa mensagem aparece quando a rota em questão não possui implementada esse protocolo HTTP

Comment: A minha se encontra assim no momento : routes.delete('/postagens/:post_id', PostController.delete)